# Show that the range of $\{x_n\}$ contains at most a finite number of elements

Tags: real-analysis

**The question is** :

> Let $\{x_n\}$ be a sequence and let $p,q$ be two positive integers such that $\sum \limits_{i={r+1}}^{r+p} {x_i} < p$ and $\sum \limits_{i={r+1}}^{r+q} \frac {1} {x_i} < q$. Then show that the range set of $\{x_n\}$ contains at most a finite number of elements.

I don't find any clue to solve it.

Comment: Your title should be your question. Please no "How can I solve it" or similar. I'll edit it for you this time so you can see.

Comment: What is $r$ here? Is it a fixed natural number, or should this hold for all $r$?

Comment: It is a fixed r.